# Авторизация без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, php

```
$('#susubmit').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.рф/login.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: $('#susubmit').serialize(),

  success: function(response) {
    //обработка успешной отправки
    alert('Успешная авторизация')
  },
  error: function(response) {
   alert('Неуспешная авторизация')
    //обработка ошибок при отправке
 }
});
});
```

login.php

```
 session_start();
$password=$_POST['password'];
...
if ($myrow['password']==$password) {
//если пароли совпадают, то запускаем пользователю сессию! Можете его поздравить, он вошел!

 $_SESSION['pass']=$myrow['password']; 
   $_SESSION['id']=$myrow['id'];//эти данные очень часто используются, вот их и будет "носить с собой" вошедший пользователь
 $_SESSION['fio']=$myrow['username'];
    }
```

Как и что нужно передать на страницу авторизации, чтобы объяснить скрипту, что такое success и что такое error

response=='LoginComplete'
response это переменная, ее заранее где-то прописывать нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче success сработает всегда, когда яваскрипт дозвонился до вашего пхп, вот там и проверяйте что ответил скрипт, скажем так:

```
success: function(response) {
    if (response=='LoginComplete') { /* авторизация прошла */ }
    else { /* неправильный логин или пароль */ }
},
error: function(response) {
   /* ошибка соединения с интернетом */
}
```

ну и в скрипте, что то такое:

```
// подключение к базе, сессии, получение пост параметров
...
if ($myrow['password']==$password) { die('LoginComplete'); } else { die('error'); }
```

Comment: response=='LoginComplete'

response это переменная, ее заранее где-то прописывать нужно?

Comment: response - это переменная, в которой хранится ответ от PHP. В PHP у вас прописано: die('LoginComplete'); что эквивалентно: echo 'LoginComplete'; die; т.е. в response будет хранится то что выведет скрипт, а он выдаст либо LoginComplete, либо error в зависимости от проверки на существование пользователя и верности пароля. короче читайте , что в данном случает, переменная response это "некая связь" между сервером (а ещё точнее скриптом login.php) и клиентом (браузером) в которой хранится результат выполнения этого скрипта (login.php)

Comment: Это не переменная, а ответ того пхп-скрипта, который отвечает за авторизацию(строка) - { die('LoginComplete'); } можно заменить на echo('LoginComplete'); exit(). Она то и присваивается переменной response

Answer (score 1):

Сначала обрабатываешь авторизацию на стороне пхп, а потом:

```
header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=utf8');  
    $send_status = array("status" => "ok", "error" = 0);  
    echo json_encode($send_status);
    exit();
```

На стороне клиента в success обрабатываешь всё что пришло, и выводишь. error не относится к авторизации пользователя, а к получении данных или неполучении от сервера на который был аякс-запрос.

Comment: Для чего, чтобы, по сути передать бинарный статус (Yes/No), а не массив данных, замороты с json?

Comment: Это просто пример, можно передавать всё что угодно, в том числе текстовый алерт об ошибке и другое. Я писал код на вскидку, так что бы автор понял принцип, а не скопипастил.